# Thinkpad Helix and touchscreen compatibility with Linux

Tags: ubuntu, rhel, thinkpad, touch-screen

I purchased a Thinkpad Helix, which is a touchscreen Thinkpad.

I immediately installed Ubuntu, replacing Windows. It mostly works except that the touchscreen only works well in Chromium/Chrome and not with other applications like the terminal, FireFox, Thunderbird, etc, etc. In Windows the touchscreen works flawlessly with any application.

Since I paid more and traded resources to get the touchscreen, I want it to work. So, I headed over to the manufacturer's website to look for Linux drivers and found this page

https://support.lenovo.com/se/en/documents/pd031426

which indicates that only RHEL is supported.

I can make do with RHEL though I do not prefer it. However I know from my RHEL server at work that Chrome/Chromium cannot be run.

So, what I need to know to decide if I want to start over with RHEL is if I install RHEL will touchscreen work with FireFox and/or other apps like it does in Windows, or will I be even worse off, since the only app where it currently works fine (Chromium/Chrome) will not run on that OS?

Comment: I don't know whether RHEL will work with your touchscreen, but [Chrome can be installed on RHEL 7](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/917293).

Comment: @StephenKitt The version they support is 6.3. The one I use at work is also 6.3. That link is very interesting but I'd be highly suspicious of that guy's solution because for Chrome to work you'd have to replace the system version of C which would likely break other things (or so my research told me with RHEL 6; Idk tho).